# Slow progress of Time machine backup

Tags: macos, backup, time-machine

I am backing up my hdd with the Time machine. Even small incremental backups take several hours. For an hour or so I am in the state "50.3 MB of 496.3MB", while in Activity Monitor I notice that mds_stores has accumulated already over 116 GB data read, and it increases by about 50 MB/s.   My Hdd is this new pcie-sdd type, so it should be efficient with this sort of backup.
Moreover in Console it is written that about 2300 files constitute this 0.5 GB of backup.

I am backing up to external usb Toshiba drive.

Am I missing something obvious? This is not normal, is it? Can I see which of these 2300 files the Time machine is currently backing up? The "preparing" phase was not so long - took about 30 minutes.

Comment: Mine was a very similar question, with no solution, yet. http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/244117/time-machine-backup-time

Comment: Indeed. I am consufed as number of files to copy is low, and these are small files. I do not see any regularities- sometimes backups are slow, sometimes they are quick, and this is not just a function of data size.  I have restarted Spotlight, but ultimately leaving the computer for whole day and night was the only solution.

Comment: My OS drive (I have a MacPro with multiple drives) only has 50GB used. I just left for a few hours, after turning off Dropbox and PogoPlug. The current backup shows 1.17GB. No idea why this much data think it changed.

Comment: @Lacek How did you achieve reducing it to .5 GB? I am excluding almost every folder including hidden one yet it shows 15 GB.

Comment: I mean incremental backup, when the computer is untouched. Then the backup size is approx 460MB in my case. I did nothing to achieve that, it just is. At the same time I have lots of apps installed, but if they are not actively used I suppose their files are unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem pretty regularly. I tried the usual tricks (stop backup, eject, mount, delete `.inProgress` files, stopping spotlight, changing the throttle priority (`sudo sysctl debug.lowpri_throttle_enabled=0`). Sometimes, this works. Other times it doesn't and it keeps crawling along at a few MB per hour.

One additional trick, that works more frequently, is to force quit the `backupd` process directly from the Disk tab of `Activity Monitor`. Then tell it to start backup. This usually works for me. Heads up: this may be a terrible idea in other ways (e.g. maybe it could damage existing backups). In my experience, it hasn't so far.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to setting `sudo sysctl debug.lowpri_throttle_enabled=0`, I've found Sophos can make backups really slow. I expect other virus scanners may have similar issues.

I found if I turn Sophos off I can make a backup complete in a reasonable time. Unfortunately we are required to use a virus scanner where I work as part of company policy, so I can't turn it off completely or remove it, only suspend it for 4 hours at a time.